# Shell script to extract image of an Android mobile

Tags: android, shell, ubuntu-14.04

So I am trying to extract the image of an Android mobile to do some forensic analysis using the adb tool. I have been able to successfully extract the image. But what I am trying now is to make a shell script for the whole extraction process. The script is as follows:--

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo adb start-server
adb shell
su
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 of=/storage/extSdCard/I1.img bs=4096
exit
exit
adb pull /storage/extSdCard/I1.img Desktop/img/
sudo adb kill-server
sudo mount -o loop Desktop/img/I1.img /mnt/a501/
```

Now after the `adb shell` command, I get access to the android device shell and post which the script gets suspended. Is there anyway I can still continue running the script form the android shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo adb start-server
adb shell<<EOF
su
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 of=/storage/extSdCard/I1.img bs=4096
exit
exit
EOF
adb pull /storage/extSdCard/I1.img Desktop/img/
sudo adb kill-server
sudo mount -o loop Desktop/img/I1.img /mnt/a501/
```

Comment: thanks for the answer mate. much appreciated!!
just needed to do a minor tweak by including the two exit commands within EOF.

could you please tell me the functionality of EOF and how it works with respect to the particular script?

Comment: Check http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
adb shell su -c dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 of=/storage/extSdCard/I1.img bs=4096
```